# Check if IP is in CIDR netmask (range)

Tags: mysql, linux, ip, cidr

I have 2 tables `ip` and `cidr`.

In the first one I store IP's. (2 column table, id, ip), here is an example (the values are fictional):

```
id | ip
---+-------------
 1 | 172.922.2.10
---+-------------
 2 | 194.22.10.13
```

In the second one I store CIDR netmask's (2 column table, id, cidr), here is an example (the values are fictional):

```
id | cidr
---+-------------
 1 | 26.232.49.0/20
---+---------------
 2 | 14.44.182.0/24
```

Is there any way to make a mysql query to check whether the ip's from the first table are in the range of any of my cidr netmasks?

Note: To convert a cidr netmask to a range of ip's click [here](http://magic-cookie.co.uk/iplist.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally recommend using postgres as it has a CIDR data-type and powerful functions to go with it, but there's an interesting discussion on doing similar things in MySQL, too.

http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=29283

Comment: The thing is that my shared hosting does not support postgres.

Comment: That's a shame. Does the link help?

Comment: I am on it right now, but it's better to write the solution in your answer because the link can disapear after a while and after that nobody can get any benefit from your answer.

Comment: Fair comment. I'm not sure whether that would be considered plagiarism if I copied &  pasted from there, though.

Comment: Well you can also mention the source and I guess it will be ok. Or you can change the texts in some way or make is more simple, IDK the definion of plagiarism.

Comment: I for one would not pick a platform based on a cidr datatype one could write in 10 minutes. Geez Louise !  :p

Comment: @Drew - I wouldn't either. Just a shameless plug for my preferred database. ;}

Comment: once I get my Gold in mysql I am joining you :p

Answer (score 0):

This has come up in a related project of mine, and this appears to be the top google result for the question, so, you get the answer!

```
create function get_lowest_ipv4(cidr char(18)) returns bigint deterministic return INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cidr, '/', 1));
create function get_highest_ipv4(cidr char(18)) returns bigint deterministic return get_lowest_ipv4(cidr) + (0x100000000 >> SUBSTRING_INDEX(cidr,'/', -1)) - 1;
```

You can then do ... `from ip_map where INET_ATON("ip.add.re.ss") between get_lowest_ipv4(ip) AND get_highest_ipv4(ip)`

Because you declare the functions as deterministic, it'll get cached inside mysql and the calculation will only need to be run once. Then it'll just be 'is integer greater than y and less than x', which will be effectively instant.

```
MySQL [astpp]> set @cidr="10.11.0.0/16";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL [astpp]> select get_lowest_ipv4(@cidr), get_highest_ipv4(@cidr), INET_NTOA(get_lowest_ipv4(@cidr)), INET_NTOA(get_highest_ipv4(@cidr));
+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| get_lowest_ipv4(@cidr) | get_highest_ipv4(@cidr) | INET_NTOA(get_lowest_ipv4(@cidr)) | INET_NTOA(get_highest_ipv4(@cidr)) |
+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|              168493056 |               168558591 | 10.11.0.0                         | 10.11.255.255                      |
+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [astpp]> set @cidr="10.11.12.1/32";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL [astpp]> select get_lowest_ipv4(@cidr), get_highest_ipv4(@cidr), INET_NTOA(get_lowest_ipv4(@cidr)), INET_NTOA(get_highest_ipv4(@cidr));
+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| get_lowest_ipv4(@cidr) | get_highest_ipv4(@cidr) | INET_NTOA(get_lowest_ipv4(@cidr)) | INET_NTOA(get_highest_ipv4(@cidr)) |
+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|              168496129 |               168496129 | 10.11.12.1                        | 10.11.12.1                         |
+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MySQL [astpp]>
```

The only important caveat is that you insert VALID CIDRs.  For example, 10.11.12.13/24 is not valid. That's an IP Address INSIDE the 10.11.12.0/24 network.

If you are unable to validate the CIDRs before inserting them (for some crazy reason), you could change get_lowest_ipv4 to do a bitwise comparison on the source, but that's much less elegant.

```
INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`ip`, '/', 1)) & 0xffffffff ^((0x1 <<(32 -  SUBSTRING_INDEX(`ip`, '/', -1))) -1 )
```

Is an (untested) stab at matching invalid CIDRs.